# Read and display JSON data from external file in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having this View.JS app where I am currently showing conversation thread from JSON. The code currently looks like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      messages:[
      {
      name: "Support",
      message: "Hey! Welcome to support"
      },
      {
      name: "Me",
      message: "Hello there!"
      },
      {
      name: "Support",
      message: "What can I do for you?"
      }
],
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <p v-for="message in messages"><b>Name: </b>{{message.name}} </br><b>Message: </b>{{message.message}}</br></p>
    </div>
  `
})
```

Now I want to have this data on a external JSON file (Called 'data.json' in the same directory) and have the same output. Any ideas on how I can do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple solution but as i believe you are very new to Vue JS and learning Vue i will keep things simple.

> Add a file data.json

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "name": "AI",
            "message": "Hello Doctor"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shri",
            "message": "Hello there!"
        },
        {
            "name": "AI",
            "message": "Hope you are well. Today’s discussion shall be on treatment options to manage ..."
        }
    ]
}
```

update your Js file as

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        messages: []
    },
    methods: {
        loadJSON(callback) {

            var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            xobj.open('GET', './data.json', true)
            xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                    // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
                    callback(xobj.responseText);
                }
            };
            xobj.send(null);
        },
        init() {
            let that = this
            that.loadJSON(function (response) {
                // Parse JSON string into object
                var data = JSON.parse(response);
                that.messages = data.messages
            });
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.init()
    },
    template: `
      <div>
        <p v-for="message in messages"><b>Name: </b>{{message.name}} </br><b>Message: </b>{{message.message}}</br></p>
      </div>
    `
})
```

loadJSON is just a basic HHTP request and load the data from json file. inside init call back you can set data to local instant

Comment: I'm getting this error: `VM57:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 9
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:24
    at XMLHttpRequest.xobj.onreadystatechange (main.js:15)` Any idea why??

Comment: use the json i posted

Comment: Thanks a tonn!! Works like charm!

Comment: Yeah got it! Thanks! Marked your answer!

Answer (score 6):

Try this

messages.json

```
{
      messages:[
      {
        name: "Support",
        message: "Hey! Welcome to support"
      },
      {
        name: "Me",
        message: "Hello there!"
      },
      {
        name: "Support",
        message: "What can I do for you?"
      }
],
  }
```

App.vue

```js
import messages from "./messages.json";
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: messages.messages,
  template: `
    <div>
      <p v-for="message in messages"><b>Name: </b>{{message.name}} </br><b>Message: </b>{{message.message}}</br></p>
    </div>
  `
})
```

> [For More Info codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/z2mpz6zq23)

Answer (score 1):

Import your json file to your file and just loop it

```
<script>
  import json from './json/data.json'
  export default{
      data(){
          return{
              messages: json
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```